# Saved trace object runs in EOFError: Ran out of input pymc3

Tags: pickle, trace, pymc3

I have ran my model and sampled the trace on a remote server. I saved the object using pickle. The file size is extremely huge. I tried to recover the trace but its running into

> EOFError: Ran out of input

I'm using this code:

```
with open('/raid60/anil.gaddam/trace_results.pkl', 'wb') as buff:
  pickle.dump({'model': model, 'trace': tr}, buff)

with open ('E:/Masters Project/dataset/results/LDA/trace_advi.pkl', 'rb') as buff:
  data = pickle.load (buff,encoding ='latin1')
  trace = data['trace']
```

Need help!
Much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!